# Chrome拡張で、固定された保存先フォルダではなく、前回保存したフォルダへ(mhtml)ファイルを保存するよう保存先設定を変更したい

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

現在のChrome拡張
常に固定されたフォルダ(C:\Users\user\Downloads)へ保存されます。
manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
```

background.js

```
  function download(filename, blob) {
    chrome.downloads.download({
      conflictAction: 'prompt',
      filename: filename,
      saveAs: true,
      url: URL.createObjectURL(blob),
    });
  }
```

前回保存したフォルダへ(mhtml)ファイルを保存するよう保存先設定を変更するにはどうすればよいですか？

Comment: 少なくとも「前回どこに保存したか」の情報を覚えて記憶させる必要がありそうです。

Comment: Windowsで右クリックして「名前を付けて保存」を選択すると、前回保存したフォルダが表示されるので、どこかにこの情報(前回どこに保存したか)は保存されているのでは？ と思ったのですが……

Comment: この記事 [\[Chrome\] ファイルダウンロード時に毎回保存先を指定するように設定する](https://pasomaki.com/chrome-file-download-confirm/) の設定で何か変わるかもしれません。ただこちらの記事 [How can I specify the download manager to save to the last directory used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60408760/9014308) でFireFoxではセキュリティの関係でそうした情報はダウンロードAPIでは利用できないとなっているようです。Chromeでも同様かもしれません。その質問でのChrome関連の話題のリンク [Issue 838952: Save As does not default to recent directory if path-less filename specified - chrome.downloads.download](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=838952)

Comment: 詳しくないので的ハズれかもしれませんが『「名前を付けて保存」を選択すると、前回保存したフォルダが表示される』機能はChrome側で制御されていて機能拡張側からはコントロールできないような気がします。